# Google search by time frame anomaly

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to understand the logic Google search uses when I use the time frame filter.

In the first search, I restrict results to "Past 24 hours":

[image: searching in the past day]

In the second search, I restrict to "Past week" :

[image: searching in the past week]

As you can see, I get one result for "Past 24 hours" but no results for "Past week".

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your results. // I tried searching within youtube with the one day filter and the one week filter, and there, the results were what they should be, i.e., the item showed up in both.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. What google domain are you using (google.com, google.co.uk, google.ca,...)?

Comment: @Rubén .com domain.

Comment: @aparente001 thanks for confirming. This is something that changes day to day so at least somebody believes me.